# Fluid Sim - Changing fluid velocity at certain location

Tags: fluid-simulation

So I have a fluid simulation where I want the fluid to hit a specific object and then flow at a slower pace. I have an effector guide in the domain that has a velocity factor change but it doesn't seem to do anything. The domain has Guides checked on and the Velocity Source marked to Effector. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you add a picture of the setup?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right you want a slow motion effect.

This can be done by giving keyframes to timescale in the domain:

[image]

In my example i change the timescale from 1 to 0.1:

[image]

Comment: This could almost work for me and might be a work around in the end if need be. My fluid sim currently has a constant flow coming out of a pipe and then hitting a separate block surface to show porous sediment, so I'm hoping to only have the fluid hitting that block slow down.

Comment: Ok, looks like I misunderstood you. Could you provide some sketch with annotations to your question to make it more clear?